# My pan gesture recognizer is very slow and unresponsive

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a pan gesture recognizer in my app that does a function when swiped down. The animation used to be smooth but all of a sudden (without adding an code to that view controller) it becomes very laggy and I have to swipe down quickly for it to do that animation, It doesn't follow my finger.

What is the cause of that

```
class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    private var backgroundImage: UIImage
    private var backgroundImageView: UIImageView?
    private var picker: UIPickerView
    var list: [String]
    var locationPicked: String
    var locationArray: [Any]
    var partyIndex: Int = Int()


    init(image: UIImage) {
        self.backgroundImage = image
        self.picker = UIPickerView()
        self.list = ["Loading..."]
        self.locationPicked = list[0]
        self.locationArray = []
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        print(image)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    /************************************/



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true{
            mapApi()
        }

        let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(frame: view.frame)
        backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImage
        backgroundImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.backgroundImageView = backgroundImageView

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerAction(_:)))
        backgroundImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

        let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longTap(sender:)))
        backgroundImageView.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)

        view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)

        view.backgroundColor = greenColor


        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width)/2)-84, y: (self.view.frame.height)-70, width: 160, height: 40)
        picker.clipsToBounds = true
        picker.layer.cornerRadius = picker.bounds.size.width/20
        picker.layer.borderColor = redColor.cgColor
        picker.layer.borderWidth = 0
        picker.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 217/255, green: 83/255, blue: 79/255, alpha: 0.85)
        backgroundImageView.addSubview(picker)

        print(list)
    }

    func panGestureRecognizerAction(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)

        if let bgImage = gesture.view{
            if list.count > 1{
                bgImage.frame.origin.y = translation.y
            }
        }
        if gesture.state == .ended{

            let tickName = "Tick.png"
            let tickImage = UIImage(named: tickName)
            let tick = UIImageView(image: tickImage!)
            tick.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width)/2)-25, y: 150, width: 70, height: 70)
            self.view.addSubview(tick)
            tick.alpha = 0

            let crossName = "Cross.png"
            let crossImage = UIImage(named: crossName)
            let cross = UIImageView(image: crossImage!)
            cross.frame = CGRect(x: ((self.view.frame.width)/2)-25, y: (self.view.frame.height)-75, width: 50, height: 50)
            self.view.addSubview(cross)
            cross.alpha = 0

            let velocity = gesture.velocity(in: view)

            if (gesture.view?.frame.origin.y)! > CGFloat(100) || velocity.y > 1500 {


                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {

                    self.view.backgroundColor = greenColor
                    gesture.view?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 275)
                    tick.alpha = 1

                }, completion: { (true) in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.2, animations: {
                        tick.alpha = 0

                    })

                    if partyAt != nil{
                        self.uploadPartyPost()
                    } else{
                        self.uploadPost()
                    }

            })

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, animations: {

                gesture.view?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

                }, completion: { (true) in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })

            //send image here tick



        } else if (gesture.view?.frame.origin.y)! < CGFloat(-80) || velocity.y > 1500 {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

                self.view.backgroundColor = redColor
                gesture.view?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -150)
                cross.alpha = 1

                }, completion: { (true) in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.7, animations: {
                        cross.alpha = 0
                    })

            })

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 1, animations: {

                gesture.view?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

            }, completion: { (true) in

                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            })

            print("Done")


            //send image here cross

        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

                gesture.view?.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well there is isn't really a point in showing the code because it was working a couple hours ago and I added nothing. I was just wondering if it is a memory leak or something @str

Comment: We cannot help without the code.

Comment: I'll edit my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

After playing with translation of Pan gesture you need to set translation point back to zero.

Comment: did not work. The code I have right now was working fine before I have not idea what happened now @vivek